# sqlite дописать новые строки в файл

Tags: sqlite, bash

Имеется `sqlite` БД. Делаю экспорт из `sqlite3` в файл, например `file_test`.
Через некоторое время хочу сделать новый экспорт, как можно дописать в `file_test`, только новые строки?

Пока приходит на ум тольк овариант, сделать экспорт в новый файл 
`sqlite3 > file_test_1`
и потом уже как-то сравнить два получившихся файла.
Возможно это реализуется средствами `sqlite3`.

Answer (score 1):

исправил ответ, так как не понял направление импорта:) В sqlite есть команда импорта, которая и будет с внешнего файла и вставляет в базу. А то, что Вы описываете в вопросе - называется экспорт.

Не вижу ничего плохого в том, что бы сделать снова импорт в файл и перезаписать данные. Для стороннего пользователя это будет выглядеть, как будто дописали новый строки. Если база не очень большая, то работать будет достаточно быстро.

Если же файл большой и строки будут только дописываться, тогда можно пойти по другому. Для этого нужно знать id последней выведенной строки. Ее можно извлечь с экспортируемого файла или отдельно сохранить выборкой `select max(id) from your_table`.

Согласно документации, [экспорт](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) делается так

```
sqlite> .header on
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .once c:/work/dataout.csv
sqlite> SELECT * FROM tab1;
sqlite> .system c:/work/dataout.csv
```

Для того, что бы сделать экспорт только "хвоста", нужно немного модифицировать запрос. Где то так

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 where id > !put here your saved id!;
```

осталось только это все завернуть в баш.

Другое дело, если id нет. В этом случае немного сложнее и менее надежно. Нужно запоминать/извлекать кол-во строк, которые уже были экспортированы, а потом использовать offset. Но только без limit offset работать не будет - поэтому указываем вместо limit достаточно большое число.

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 limit 1000000 offset !put here your saved id!;
```

Comment: А что не так в ответе? не получилось сделать? или просто увидели `insert or ignore` и решили, что это не то, что нужно?

Comment: Вопрос же стоит об импорте данных в отдельный плоский файл без его полного перезаписывания, а не работой с таблицами.

Comment: поправил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

как вариант, можем вставлять в таблицу из новой-добавочной только записи большие по уникальному ключу, чем последний в старой

Comment: Вопрос же вовсе не в добавлении записей в таблицу, а скорее наоборот. Я не нашел чего-либо похожего в man.